# Where is Karliah and why haven't I been given the follow-up quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After the quest "Hard Answers", Karliah told me to meet her at the Ragged Flagon, but it never came up in my journal or even came up as a quest.

I go to meet her at the Ragged Flagon and she isn't there. Tried going back to the Sanctum where we first met and she was there, trapped behind a door. I opened the door to free her and tried talking again but she doesn't say anything. I tried going back to the Ragged Flagon again but she still is not there.

Comment: If a NPC is trapped, they can't get to their destination.  After you free her, you might try just waiting at the Flagon for a couple of days - she might just pop up.  NPCs tend to travel somewhat slowly.

Answer (score 4):

[As mentioned by agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91611/where-is-karliah-and-why-havent-i-been-given-the-follow-up-quest#comment124911_91611), you could try waiting a couple of days (in-game) for her in The Ragged Flagon.

If playing in the PC, an alternative workaround is to use console commands to teleport Karliah to your location.

Console commands to teleport Karliah to the player's current location (make sure you are in The Ragged Flagon before you input the commands):
`prid 58F1A`
`moveto player`

`prid` targets an entity - [Karliah](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Karliah) in this case. '58F1A' is Karliah's [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs). `moveto player` moves that targeted entity near the vicinity of the player.

Karliah should now be near you after doing this.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Answer (score 1):

Type

> recycleactor 00058F1A

in console

Answer (score 0):

I found her stuck behind that door too. What I did was make her mad at me, then leave fast and then travel to the Thieves Guild cistern. I got that poison affect from her arrow there and then it started me over to speaking with silence.